# Pandas read_excel get only last row

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have an excel that is generated daily and can have up to 50k+ rows. Is there a way to read only the last row (which is the sum of the columns)?

right now I am just reading the entire sheet and keeping only the last row but it is taking up a huge amount of runtime.

my code:

```
df=pd.read_excel(filepath,header=1,usecols="O:AC")
df=df.tail(1)
```

Comment: pd.read_excel has parameter `skiprows` https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html

Comment: import pandas as pd

dashboard = pd.read_excel('example.xlsx', sheet_name = 'Dashboard')
print(dashboard.tail(1))

Answer (score 0):

Pandas is quite slow, especially with large in memory data. You can think about a lazy loading method, for example check [dask](http://dask.org).
Else you can read the file using "open" and read the last line :

```
with open(filepath, "r") as file:
last_line = file.readlines()[-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

**I dont think there is a way to decrease runtime when you read excel file.**
When you read a excel or one sheet of excel,you would load excel all data into dask,even you use pd.read_excel **skiprows,Its just keep the row the skiprows choose after you load all data into dask**.So it cant decrease runtime.
If you really want decrease runtime of read file,you should save the file into another format,.csv or .txt and so on.

**AND you generally you can't read Microsoft Excel files as a text files using methods like readlines or read.** You should convert files to another format before (good solution is .csv which can be readed by csv module) or use a special python modules like pyexcel and openpyxl to read .xlsx files directly.